Proving a lattice is distributive.
The problem is:
Let $L$ be a lattice, prove that:
$L$ is distributive if and only if $a \land c = b \land c$ and $a \lor c = b \lor c$ imply $a = b$ for all $a, b, c \in L$.
My attempt:
I know how to prove $a \land c = b \land c$ and $a \lor c = b \lor c$ imply $a = b$ for all $a, b, c \in L$ if $L$ is distributive. But I don't konw how to prove the converse of it, i.e., if  $a \land c = b \land c$ and $a \lor c = b \lor c$ imply $a = b$ for all $a, b, c \in L$, then show that L is a distributive lattice.
I considered I should find a $x \in L$ that makes $(a \land (b \lor c)) \land x = ((a\land b) \lor (a \land c)) \land x$ and $(a \land (b \lor c)) \lor x = ((a\land b) \lor (a \land c)) \lor x$ hold, but I don't know how to find this $x$

Is this question and answer helpful?

Neither the diamond $M_3$ nor the pentagon $N_5$ satisfy that implication. Since every non-distributive lattice has a sublattice isomorphic to one of those...
